# How to display png from JSON in ReactJS (create-react-app)?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, image

I'm trying to display a png file that I included in my JSON. 
I have an array that looks like follow:

```
{
  "clientsArray": [
    {
      "name": "XYZ",
      "image": "../clientsIMG/xyz.png",
      "altIMG": ""
    }
]
}
```

and here is my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/style.css";

import Client from "./Client";

class Clients extends Component {
render() {

    const { clientsArray } = this.props;
    const clientsList = clientsArray.clientsArray.map((company, i) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <li>{company.name}</li>
                <img src={company.image} alt={company.altIMG}></img>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{clientsList}</ul>
            <Client></Client>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Clients;
```

so now on my app I can see properly the name of my "client" but the image is not displayed.

My folder structure is as follow:

```
src--------- assets
                    ---clientsIMG/xyz.png
                    ---json/clients.json
     --- components
                    ---clients.js
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting DOM? and see which URL your <img src is getting? and is it correct one or not?

Comment: You actually needed to import the image before usage since it's in your project directory and not an external link. Use this instead: 
`<img src={require(company.image)} alt={company.altIMG}></img>`

Comment: Well at the moment with this path directory link after inspect looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/clientsIMG/xyz.png

seems like it missing assets? but I've tried to go higher up in folders
I changed my JSON into: 
"image": "../../assets/clientsIMG/xyz.png" 
but then I see this:
<img src="(unknown)" alt="">

Comment: Balanced02 
I am getting this error (in chrome):
Cannot find module "."
webpackMissingModule
src/components/Clients.js:14

and in my vsc terminal:
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/Clients.js
53:54-76 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Answer (score 0):

so I solved this issue by removing my images from src folder into public folder.
In clientsArray I changed directory (check below) and I kept my component like you see in the first post.

```
      {
  "clientsArray": [
    {
      "name": "XYZ",
      "image": "./clientsIMG/xyz.png",
      "altIMG": ""
    }
]
}
```

But I have some doubts if that's a good practice so if someone smarter could confirm I would appreciate that.